# How do you bind the ApacheHttpClient with an Amazon S3 Object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The Amazon S3 docs in the *Java V2 Developer Guide* state that you can use **[ApacheHttpClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/http/apache/ApacheHttpClient.html)**.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/http-configuration.html

However, I am not sure how to bind that with the S3Client object. Can someone please show me the proper logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are examples of using **ApacheHttpClient** when creating an AWS Service Client in Java V2. Included in this doc is the dependencies that you need as well.

See the examples under ***Specify the HTTP client to use at client creation time***.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-sdk-for-java-2-x-released/